# C# + SQLite. Вопрос для знающих

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, sqlite

**Всем привет, у меня вопрос.**
 Я тут пишу программку на c#, что-то вроде AIMP (просто для практики) и мне знакомый программист сказал что бы я использовал SQLite, я кучу всего переискал и не могу понять: **ЗАЧЕМ МНЕ НАДО ЭТОТ SQLITE?!** Я вообще не понимаю для чего нужны эти базы данных. Подскажите, кто знает или скиньте ссылку на инфу. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: если вы пишите desktop приложение, то пользуйтесь встроенным ПО (пердполагается что Вы используете Visual Studio). Для начала подробнее опишите приложение (имеется ввиду ПО, которое вы используете для написания), которое Вы пишете. Базы данных тоже бывают разные, но выполняют одну главную функцию - хранят данные. Остальные функции могут отличаться в зависимости от вида БД и СУБД.

Comment: И вообще, зачем приложению типа Aimp нужна БД??? Плэйлист хранить?

Comment: А настройки приложения? Я вообще не вдупляю зачем эти БД.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы не знаете, зачем вам база данных, значит, она вам не нужна. По крайней мере пока не нужна. 
Ждать ответа для чего БД нужна именно вам, смысла не имеет, так как только вы знаете все требования к вашему приложению.

Comment: Я же начинающий, и пытаюсь разобраться во всем, что не понимаю. Дак для чего же нужна БД?

Comment: @KirillStepankov вам не будут такие вещи объяснять, так как это гуглится за 10 секунд. [База_данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), [Система управления базами данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), [Реляционная СУБД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%94)

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо).